# Error Creating Index Using SDK When analyzers or tokenFilters Elements are Present

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have an index definition that includes a token filter definition and a corresponding *custom* analyzer definition as shown below.

```
  "suggesters": [],
  "scoringProfiles": [],
  "defaultScoringProfile": "",
  "corsOptions": null,
  "analyzers": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",
      "name": "test_soundex",
      "tokenizer": "standard_v2",
      "tokenFilters": [
        "lowercase",
        "test_phonetic"
      ],
      "charFilters": []
    }
  ],
  "charFilters": [],
  "tokenFilters": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.PhoneticTokenFilter",
      "name": "test_phonetic",
      "encoder": "soundex",
      "replace": false
    }
  ],
  "tokenizers": [],
```

When I attempt to create a new index using this definition I get the following error:

Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException: The request is invalid. Details: index : A type named ‘Analyzer’ could not be resolved by the model. When a model is available, each type name must resolve to a valid type.

If I remove the analyzers and tokenFilters elements from the definition the index gets created with no issue.  If I remove the custom analyzer definition I get a similar error where "A type named ‘TokenFilter’ could not be resolved by the model".

I’m running with the latest version of the SDK (10.1.0).

For further clarity here is the code that I'm using to create the index.  I'm not instantiating the Analyzer directly.  It's being created when the Index object is deserialized below.

```
        var text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"index.json");
        var indexDefinition = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Index>(text);
        _searchServiceClient.Indexes.Create(indexDefinition);
```

I know the index definition is valid as the same JSON works fine for creating the index when submitted using the API via Postman.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Please share your code that uses the SDK in order to make the question as helpful as possible. Thanks!

Comment: @Bruce Johnston  For further clarity here is the code that I'm using to create the index. I'm not instantiating the Analyzer directly. It's being created when the Index object is deserialized below. var text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"index.json"); var indexDefinition = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Index>(text); _searchServiceClient.Indexes.Create(indexDefinition);

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON deserializer needs to instantiate a `CustomAnalyzer` instead of an `Analyzer`. The `Analyzer` class ought to be abstract, but isn’t currently. Unless you use the same JSON serializer settings as the SDK itself, you won't be able to successfully serialize and deserialize SDK model classes on your own. This is not actually a supported scenario -- you might be able to get it to work, but it's not something we test.

As an aside for folks who might instantiate `Analyzer` manually by mistake, we're working on [a new .NET SDK for Azure Cognitive Search](https://www.nuget.org/packages/azure.search.documents) that is currently in preview. In the new library, `Analyzer` has been renamed to `LexicalAnalyzer` and its constructor is no longer accessible.